# Laravel Redirect Intended does nothing

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I currently have a authenticate function I hit at login from a Vue component. Right now it logs the user in but no redirect happens from the controller. I am not sure if using a Vue component is causing that. Maybe I can return the intended URL in a response if so?

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {

        //Validate the login and log errors if any
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'     => 'required',
            'password'  => 'required',
        ]);

        //if they have stuff posted get it
        $email      = $request->get('email');
        $password   = $request->get('password');


        //See if they are actually a user
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {

          return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');

        } else {
          return response()->json([
            'response' => 'error',
            'error' => 'Email or Password not correct.',
          ]);
        }
    }
```

Login method in my login.vue component:

```
login(){

             this.isLoading = true;

             this.form.post('/login')
                .then(data => {

                  this.isLoading = false

                  if(data.response == 'success'){

                     //Maybe get a url in the response and redirect here??

                  } else {
                    this.serverError= data.error
                  }

                })
                .catch(error => {
                  this.isLoading = false
                })

           }
```

Using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Redirect from vuejs . Not from laravel

Comment: Redirecting from Laravel for a RESTful API doesn't make much sense as I see it. I would return the user instance or something like that and make the redirect from the frontend.

Comment: I just posted the answer that worked for me. I just return the intended URL to my front end and let that handle it. Thanks @user2486

Comment: Don't forget selecting your own answer as accepted.

Comment: any reason you are not using the out of the box Auth setup, that does this all for you by default?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking:

in my authenticate function:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {

            return response()->json([
              'response' => 'success',
              'url' => Session::get('url.intended', url('/'))
            ]);

        } else {
          return response()->json([
            'response' => 'error',
            'error' => 'Email or Password not correct.',
          ]);
        }
```

in my vue component login method

```
if(data.response == 'success'){
                    //console.log(data);
                    window.location.href = data.url
                  } else {
                    this.serverError= data.error
                  }
```

Comment: check my answer about. it seems you want to expect a URL string result rather than a HTML response. since vue is a javascript

Comment: @KennethSunday yep, looks like we posted the same type of thing. I was just confused at first since no redirect was happening but realized I needed my front end to handle that with my setup

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the method intended, why not use `redirect()->route()` instead?

Or you are expecting a URL response. You should not use the `redirect()` method.

For your given code, you might want to consider this.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {

            return response()->json([
              'response' => 'success',
              'url' => Session::get('url.intended', route('route_of_your_dashboard'))
            ]);

        } else {
          return response()->json([
            'response' => 'error',
            'error' => 'Email or Password not correct.',
          ]);
        }
```